# Why do I suddenly need to declare a variable as "final" when adding an ActionListener to a button?

Tags: java, jframe, jbutton, actionlistener, final

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are only final variables accessible in anonymous class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732544/why-are-only-final-variables-accessible-in-anonymous-class)

This is the code I have for a "random math game" I'm creating for class:

```
package RandomMathGame;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class RandomMathGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RandomProblemGenerator randomProblems = new RandomProblemGenerator(10);
        final int numberProblems = 10;
        int correctScore = 0;
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
       int answer;
        int correctAnswer;
        JLabel[] mathProblems = new JLabel[numberProblems];
        final JTextField[] mathAnswers = new JTextField[numberProblems];
        JLabel[] correctYesNo = new JLabel[numberProblems];
        final JLabel score = new JLabel(correctScore + "/10");
        JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");
        for (int i = 1; i <= numberProblems; i++)
        {
            final int X = randomProblems.createNumberX();
            final int Y = randomProblems.createNumberY();

            mathProblems[i] = new JLabel("" + X + " * " + Y + " = ");
            mathAnswers[i] = new JTextField();


             answer = Integer.parseInt(mathAnswers[i].getText());
             correctAnswer = X * Y;

            if (answer == correctAnswer)
            {
                correctYesNo[i] = new JLabel("Correct answer; good job!");
                correctScore = correctScore + 1;
            }
            else
            {
               correctYesNo[i] = new JLabel("Incorrect answer; try again!");

            }
             panel.add(mathProblems[i]);
             panel.add(mathAnswers[i]);
             panel.add(correctYesNo[i]);
            }
      submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                score.setText("Score: " + correctScore + "/10");
            }
        });



        panel.add(submit);
        panel.add(score);

        JFrame gameFrame = new JFrame();
        gameFrame.setTitle("Random Math Game");
        gameFrame.setSize(150, 150);
        gameFrame.setVisible(true);
        gameFrame.setContentPane(panel);



        }
  }
```

I'm getting an error that the correctScore variable has to be declared as final before it can be used by the ActionListener. But when I set correctScore as a final, it causes all kinds of other errors. Can anybody think of a way to resolve this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4732617/597657

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To pass a local variable to an anonymous class, it has to be final - that is part of the Java language. Now when a primitive variable is final, you can't modify it, hence the issues you get when making `correctScore` final.

A workaround is to use a temporary variable right before the `addActionListener` call:

```
final int temp = correctScore;
```

and use that `temp` variable in your `actionPerformed` method.

Note that when you do that, any future changes to correctScore will **not** be reflected in the value of temp.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, If you want to access a local variable from within a local class (

```
new ActionListener() {
...
...
}
```

is a new local anonymous class)
the variable must be declared as final.

Local classes cannot access local variable of the enclosing method without `final` modifier
for example:

```
public class Main {
    private int b=5;
    public void bla() {
    int a = 5;
    ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            a = 4; // Error. a must be final
            b = 5; // OK!
        }
    };
  }
}
```

A possible solution to your problem is using variables declared outside of any methods (b in the above example)

Comment: As written, that's not true. I access non-final variables from the enclosing class all the time, in cases just like this: an ActionListener updating values in controls. Maybe there's a piece you've left out that would make this statement true.

Comment: Sorry, I miss wrote that. class variables, can be access (i.e members - private, public etc). local variable of the method containing the anonymous class, must be final. editing my answer

Answer (score -1):

You are getting that message because you have declared JLabel score to be final. You can't use a non-final variable to set a value for a final variable. I don't know why you want to make score final. Just remove that final.

Edit: I missed that correctScore is a function variable on my first reading. If you make it a class variable I think many of your problems will go away.